# Xamarin ImageButton states

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to create an ImageButton that uses a different image for the normal (unpressed) state and the state where the user is actively pressing the button. I found an article that uses a VisualStateGroup to change the appearance of the button based on the state:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton#imagebutton-visual-states

I am able to successfully use this to change the image. However, if I set a different image for the 'Pressed' state, when I click on the button, it does change to the new image as expected, but when I release the button it's visual state continues to display the pressed image and does not return to the 'Normal' state until I click somewhere else in the window. The XAML I am using to set the states is as follows:

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Scale"
                        Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/changeuser.png" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Scale"
                        Value="0.8" />
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/changeuser_highlight.png" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? Is there a different state than 'Pressed' that I should be using. Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this UWP-specific?

Comment: I just tested this under Android, and it does appear to be an issue to UWP. Is this simply a bug in the UWP implementation?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue at my side, it works in Android, but not work in uwp, I have reported this issue at github, Any update, I will let you know,please wait for minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Released to return the initial image.
For me it worked.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Released">
  <VisualState.Setters>
      <Setter Property="Scale"
              Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="Source" 
              Value="Assets/changeuser.png" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```